# Retrieve 2 different languages at once

Tags: c#, localization

I have a C# project and I read the label to display from resources *resx*.

The client asked me to display for each label in a form, the text in English and Italian. I have 2 resx with the same key, one for English and another one for Italian.

I was thinking to setup the culture when the form is opening

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT", true);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT", true);
```

but this is shown only the label in Italian. Is there an efficient way to read the same key in 2 different culture?

Comment: It would probably depend on how you intend on displaying the text.

Comment: You cannot talk the client out of that? I get that it would be really handy if you have Italian _and_ international users working at the same time with the same UI. But other than that it would seem rather awkward to me.

Comment: You can retrieve individual strings from a different culture using ResourceManager. But you probably wanted a way to set everything instead (?). So create a combined resx file for this mutant culture? It is XML, should be feasible to do that programatically at/before build time.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a bad idea, and something clients request without knowing the consequences of what they are asking. It's bad UI/UX and I would recommend pushing back on the idea in the first place.

Comment: ^^ This. As I hinted to before, sometimes problems can (and should) be solved better by consultation rather that development.

Comment: I agree that request is quite strange, but for SO we already have a question showing how to load string for an arbitrary language (picked as duplicate). If you are looking for more of a broader design (i.e. how to implement custom control that loads strings from multiple languages and how to allow nicer customization of such control) it may be too broad for SO. As usual feel free to [edit] the post to clarify if you are looking for just loading text yourself (as in current duplciate) or something else (ideally edit in the link to current duplciate with explanation why it is not a right answer)